# What do the colors for the contexts in the dialogflow test console UI mean?

Tags: dialogflow-es

When we test an agent in dialogflow using the "try it now" console we get the active contexts for the current intent displayed under the bot response as the image shows.

The contexts are colored, green , blue and orange. Do these colors have any meaning?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When an intent is matched, any configured output contexts for that intent become active. While any contexts are active, Dialogflow is more likely to match intents that are configured with input contexts that correspond to the currently active contexts. When a context is active, it takes a color so that you can differentiate between what is running in your chat bot and what is not.

Comment: so the orange ones are the active ones, but what's the difference between the blue and green ones?

Comment: They don't really have a difference, as I mentioned the colors are a way for you to identify each one of them.